# Position relative parent with absolute child

Tags: css, css-position

How would I go about absolutely positioning the child to the right side of the parent (with margin on all sides of the child element)? Why does the child cause the parent (with a `min-height`) to generate a scrollbar when the child falls outside of the normal flow of the document? What must I do to get rid of that scrollbar?

Alternatively, how could I use the calc() function in the context of a relative position of the child so I get the same outcome?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: hsl(220, 80%, 50%);
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  min-height: inherit;
  background: firebrick;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `min-height: inherit;` on the child inherits the value from the parent which is `400px`, and the `margin: 20px;` makes the total height over 100%, and you have `overflow: auto;` sets there, it means the scrollbar will appear if the container couldn't hold the content inside.

If they are in the normal content flow, the scrollbar won't appear, since it is `min-height`, the container will adjust the height to fit the content. However, in the `relative` and `absolute` positions, the absolute box is taken out the normal flow, the container won't able to adjust the height to fit automatically, and that will cause the overflow when the child's height exceeds.

To get rid of the scrollbar, you can use `calc()` function like you mentioned. You just need to set `min-height: calc(100% - 40px);` on the child. Or, change `overflow` value to `hidden` on the parent, the output will be different though.

By the way, since you have `box-sizing: border-box;` declared, but it does not do anything for `margin`.